# How can I optimize his sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

The Problem is that we have a Table called [TblLogEntry]. Every log-Data will written in this Table. The query takes too much time to be executed (6 Second).

The Second Problem is, this Table belongs to a Third Party Software. We created a own Webinterface to upload/transfer data to this Software (This Software dont have a own Webinterface). Im trying to find a file (Not realy a file but if I get a result form the query, then I know that the file was successfully transfered), between a specific time Range, with a the text "success". I have LIKE expressions with wilcards in it, do you have any Idea to rewrite this.

I'm trying to check if a File is uploaded succesfully or not. I have only this table to check.

**Edit: Changed Between Expression to this >= and < improved the execution. Now it takes 5 Second ^^**

```
SELECT
[Text]
,[Date_Changed]
FROM [RM_ARCHIV].[dbo].[TblLogEntry]
where Date_Changed **>=** '2019-12-07 14:24:00' Date_Changed **<=** '2019-12-07 14:25:00'
AND [Text] like '%fdnpst-121422_mongo_Test_B_C001_S001.tif%'
AND [Text] like '%success%';
```

Indexes:

```
EXEC sp_helpindex '[RM_ARCHIV].[dbo].[TblLogEntry]' GO
```

Result:
[Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RANXl.jpg)

If the query is True, I only expect a resultset,

Thanks to All! I have to find an other Table to check the query.

Comment: How does your query plan look like? What indexes do you have? Can you rewrite the LIKE expression not to use the prefix %?

Comment: The Second Problem is, this Table belongs to a Third Party Software. We created a own Webinterface to upload/transfer data to this Software (This Software dont have a own Webinterface). Im trying to find a file, between a specific time Range, with a the text "success". I have LIKE expressions with wilcards in it, do you have any Idea to rewrite this.

Comment: The query looks fine and at first glance there is nothing to optimize. (Only datetime comparisions should better be made with `>=` and `<`. You are including the second  fraction 14:25:00,0000 but excluding 14:25:00,0001 for instance, which may not be desired.) As to speed: add an index on `date_changed, text`, if such doesn't exist, yet.

Comment: By "this Table belongs to a Third Party Software" do you mean you can't make any changes to it? Or you are reluctant to make changes to it? Does the table have any existing indexes on it? Please script out existing indexes and add them to your question.

Comment: Thats the Problem, I cant make any changes to it. 

With this Query: 
EXEC sp_helpindex '[RM_ARCHIV].[dbo].[TblLogEntry]'
GO

I got this
index_name                   #     index_description #        index_keys
######################################################
IX_TblLogEntry_ID_Log nonclustered located on PRIMARY ID_Log
PK_TblLogEntry clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY ID

Comment: You need to indicate the columns in the index. Please edit the quesiton, without using images and indicate the full index definition including columns

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry but I didnt understand you

Comment: See all those # symbols in your prior comment? We need to know the columns that are in there.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid sorry but I can only add a Link from a Picture (Already Done).

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT [Text], [Date_Changed]
FROM [RM_ARCHIV].[dbo].[TblLogEntry]
WHERE Date_Changed BETWEEN '2019-12-07 14:24:00' AND '2019-12-07 14:25:00' AND
      [Text] like '%fdnpst-121422_mongo_Test_B_C001_S001.tif%' AND
      [Text] like '%success%';
```

You want an index on `(Date_Changed, Text)`.  This is a covering index for the query.  That means that the index can satisfy the query without referring to the original data pages.

You are selecting data from about 61 seconds of data, so this should be pretty fast.  Then several things could be going on.

If `Text` is really big (many thousands of characters or larger), then parsing it might be expensive.  A full text index might help, but that will slow down inserts.

If lots of rows are being inserted (dozens or hundreds per second), then even 61 seconds might be a lot of data.  That could slow down the query.

And, if lots of rows are being inserted, then the database may simply be very busy with locking and inserting, leaving few resources for your particular query.

Comment: The Problem is that many rows are being inserted in a short time

Comment: @YavuzYilmaz . . . In that case, you may need a bigger server.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will talk with our department about this Topic.